complex step derivative for gradient with complex values variables
Can the complex step derivative (https://mdolab.engin.umich.edu/wiki/guide-complex-step-derivative-approximation) be used for functions of complex variables ?
$f: \mathbb{C^n} \mapsto   \mathbb{C^n} $ or $f: \mathbb{C^n} \mapsto   \mathbb{R^n}$
I read the papers, but couldn't figure it out.
My problem is this: I have 4 equations.

$e = m - y$,
$y = W_3 z$
$z = e^{t\, ( A + W_2 )} b $
$A = \text{diag}(i \,  W_1 \, x) $, where

$y, m \in \mathbb{R}$,
$z,b,x \in \mathbb{C^n}$
$W_1, W_2, A \in \mathbb{C^{nxn}} $, $W_3 \in \mathbb{C^{1xn}}$
I need to update matrices $W_1$, $W_2$, and $W_3$ by using gradient descent in order to minimize the cost function: $J = e^T e$
Equation 3) is very hard. So I was thinking about using the complex step derivative method.

The whole point of complex step is that $f(x)$ is real but $f(x+h)$ is not so taking the imaginary part can extract the perturbation accurately. So I doubt it
